# How to detect mouse position on custom CellRenderer

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

It makes a while that I've been struggling to detect the mouse coordinates over a custom `Gtk.CellRenderer`.

I've been reading some good docs like:

- [RedHat doc](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/objects.html)
- [lazka.github](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/CellRenderer.html)

But I still not sure of how to do it. I've tried many things like trying to connect a signal with `__gsignals__` or by trying to use the virtual methods.

I need to do this because I'm building a rating widget. The raiting widget contain starts like: `★★★★★` and I'd like that when the user pases the mouse over, the relative `x` position modifies the number of starts.

I also would like to connect a `clicked` signal in order to save the number of starts that the user selected.

Here below is my current working code. Any help on this is highly appreciated!

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('PangoCairo', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, cairo, Pango, PangoCairo, GObject

class CellRendererRating(Gtk.CellRenderer):
    """ Cellrenderer to display ratings from 0 to 5: ★★★★★, ★★★☆☆, etc """

    __gproperties__ = {
        'rating': ( int, # type
                    "integer prop", # nick
                    "A property that contains an integer", # blurb
                    0, # min
                    5, # max
                    0, # default
                    GObject.PARAM_READWRITE # flags
                    ),
    }

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.font_size=15
        self.font="Sans Bold {}".format(self.font_size)
        self.rating = 0

    def activate(event, widget, path, background_area, cell_area, flags):
        print(path)

    def do_set_property(self, pspec, value):
        setattr(self, pspec.name, value)

    def do_get_property(self, pspec):
        return getattr(self, pspec.name)

    def do_get_size(self, widget, cell_area):
        return (0, 0, self.font_size*5, self.font_size+5)

    def do_start_editing(event, widget, path, background_area, cell_area, flags):
        print('called')

    def do_render(self, cr, treeview, background_area, cell_area, flags):
        cr.translate (0, 0)
        layout = PangoCairo.create_layout(cr)
        #layout.set_font_description(FONT_CELLRATING_DESCRIPTION)

        if 'GTK_CELL_RENDERER_FOCUSED' in str(flags) and self.rating < 5:
            for i in range(5):
                if i < self.rating:
                    layout.set_text("★", -1)
                else:
                    layout.set_text("☆", -1)

                cr.save()
                PangoCairo.update_layout (cr, layout)
                cr.move_to (cell_area.x+i*(self.font_size+1), cell_area.y)
                PangoCairo.show_layout (cr, layout)
                cr.restore()

        else:
            for i in range(self.rating):
                layout.set_text("★", -1)
                cr.save()
                PangoCairo.update_layout (cr, layout)
                cr.move_to (cell_area.x+i*(self.font_size+1), cell_area.y)
                PangoCairo.show_layout (cr, layout)
                cr.restore()

GObject.type_register(CellRendererRating)


if __name__ == '__main__':


    class Window(Gtk.Window):
        def __init__(self):
            Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
            self.connect('destroy', self.on_quit)

            liststore = Gtk.ListStore(int)

            for i in range(6):
                liststore.append([i])


            treeview = Gtk.TreeView(liststore)

            treeviewcolumn = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Rating")
            treeviewcolumn.set_resizable(True)
            cellrenderer = CellRendererRating()
            treeviewcolumn.pack_start(cellrenderer, True)
            treeviewcolumn.add_attribute(cellrenderer, 'rating', 0)
            treeview.append_column(treeviewcolumn)

            self.add(treeview)
            self.show_all()

        def on_quit(self, widget, data=None):
            Gtk.main_quit()

    w = Window()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get the position of the cursor on a `CellRenderer` by doing:

```
def do_render(self, cr, treeview, background_area, cell_area, flags):
    mouse_x, mouse_y = treeview.get_pointer()
    cell_render_x = mouse_x - cell_area.x
    cell_render_y = mouse_y - cell_area.y
```

Yet this might not be the optimal solution for your issue as there is already a Rating-`CellRenderer` that does exactly what you're trying to do namely [`RB.CellRendererRating`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#RB-3.0/classes/CellRendererRating.html#RB.CellRendererRating). I would recommend using their implementation, either as is or as the basis for your custom version.

> **RB.CellRendererRating.new()**
>
> Create a cell renderer that will display some pixbufs for representing the rating of a song. It is also able to update the rating.

[Source of `RB.CellRendererRating`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/rhythmbox/tree/widgets/rb-cell-renderer-rating.c)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I haven't had the change to take a deep look to the `RB.CellRendererRating` but I think that its some C widget for the rythmbox player. I think that I'll rather making my own widget and learning a little bit about `CellRenderers` than struggle to use the C widget, but anyways your answer helps me.